# NFS Mount failed and now it says `Device not configured`

Tags: macos, network, mount, nfs

I have Macbook Pro 2015, running El Capitan 10.11.1 and I am having issues with NFS mounts. I also have an Android TV Box and it mounts NFS without any issues, so I guess the issue is with my laptop. Here is the NFS config(`/etc/exports`):

```
/media/mypassport 192.168.2.0/24(insecure,rw,all_squash,anonuid=1000,anongid=1000,no_subtree_check)
```

When I run showmount:

```
$ showmount -e rpi

Exports list on rpi:
/media/mypassport                   192.168.2.0/24
```

I mount from Finder > Go > Connect to Server and enter: `nfs://rpi/media/mypassport`

This mounts my NFS drive, however sometimes it disconnects and I am not able to remount again. I have to restart my machine and keep trying till it doesn't disconnect.

When I `ls` into `/Volumes` I get following error:

```
$ ls

ls: mypassport: Device not configured
Macintosh HD
```

Whats the issue here? Why it keeps unmounting or gets disconnected? And how do I remount without restarting?

Comment: Let's take a look at your logs on ***both*** machines.  On your Mac, issue the command `syslog | grep -i nfs`.  I don't know what you are running as your host, but you can try the same command there.  If you see anything, rerun the command and append `| pbcopy` to the command so it outputs to your clipboard for pasting here

Comment: NFS is being run in Raspberry Pi and it uses Raspibian Jessie. Let me post logs

Comment: I don't know whats the syslog equivalent for Pi, so I posted output from `dmesg`. Here is the log from my laptop - [link](http://dpaste.com/2VHHBZD) and here is the link to that of Pi - [link](http://dpaste.com/3ZXVECT)

Comment: Are you running a firewall on your Mac?  If so, turn it off

Comment: No, firewall is already off.

Comment: btw here is another log, did reboot and mounted. I didn't use `grep filter` cos there seem to be lines without `nfs` but relevant - [link](http://dpaste.com/3QNQC35)

Answer (score 1):

### Restart NFS without Rebooting

Issue the following command in Terminal:

```
sudo nfsd restart
```

This has the effect of stopping the NFS daemon, starting it back up, rereading your config and processing what's in your `/etc/exports`

### OS X Disconnecting from NFS

Try this:

`find . -name ._* | xargs rm` on the R-Pi  in the directory that gets mounted.  That will remove any of the hidden "_filename" files that OS X creates when going through a directory

Based on this Apple Support Forum with similar symptoms:  https://discussions.apple.com/thread/2733032?start=0&tstart=0

Comment: It disconnects in one or two minutes. For example, I have mounted the drive and using chrome or anything else, the mac would be still on and not going to sleep. And yet it disconnects.